# Partial Underline check for a shape in Powerpoint not working?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, partial, shapes, underline

```
ppShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Underline == MsoTriState.msoTrue
ppShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Underline == MsoTriState.msoFalse
ppShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Underline == MsoTriState.msoTriStateMixed
```

The above code checks whether a powerpoint shape has...
1. all the text underlined
2. all the text not underlined
3. partial text are underlined

The 3rd point, partial text are underlined are not working and returns false or true randomly for mixed underlinetext in shape.

This works perfectly fine for Bold and Italic, i.e

```
ppShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold == MsoTriState.msoTriStateMixed
ppShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Italic == MsoTriState.msoTriStateMixed
```

I also raised issue with Microsoft about this issue here in GitHub,
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/VBA-Docs/issues/462

Let me know if there are any way to fix this issue or at least there is any alternative work around for this problem ???

Comment: Update 1: Microsoft took the ticket for development. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/VBA-Docs/issues/462

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for shedding light on TextRange.Runs methods, which really is wonderful function which also saves a lot of performance rather than looping character.

I created a similar function in C#.Net to use it readily similar to default function.

```
using pp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;

public static MsoTriState IsUnderlined(pp.Shape parShape)
{
    int cntUnderline = 0;

    foreach (pp.TextRange textTR in parShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Runs())
    {
        if (textTR.Font.Underline == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
        {
            cntUnderline++;
        }
    }

    if (cntUnderline == 0)
    {
        //No Underline
        return MsoTriState.msoFalse;
    }
    else if (parShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Runs().Count == cntUnderline)
    {
        //All Underline
        return MsoTriState.msoTrue;
    }
    else if (parShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Runs().Count != cntUnderline)
    {
        //Mixed Underline
        return MsoTriState.msoTriStateMixed;
    }

    return MsoTriState.msoTriStateToggle; //Consider as error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can check each Run in the TextRange. In VBA, you could pass the shape to a function like this:

```
Function IsUnderlined(oSh As Shape) As Boolean
    Dim oRng As TextRange
    For Each oRng In oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Runs
        If oRng.Font.Underline Then
            IsUnderlined = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

If any character in the text is underlined, the function will return True.